# row id to column keeping date intact

Tags: r, date, row

I have a dataframe named df_high_A like this

```
            C1  C2
02-01-07    10  23
03-01-07    20  12
04-01-07    14  17
```

Want to make it like this

```
      C1        C2  C3
    02-01-07    10  23
    03-01-07    20  12
    04-01-07    14  17
```

when i use this code

```
library (tibble)
    df_high_A<-tibble::rowid_to_column(data.frame(df_high_A),"date")
```

it looks like this

```
C1  C2  C3
1   10  23
2   20  12
3   14  17
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Can you `dput()` the head of your dataset? I don't see why the tibble function shouldn't work.

Comment: tibble function works but it eleminates all the dates. what would be within the bracket? sorry could not percieve your instruction .

Comment: Replace `rowid_to_column` with `rownames_to_column` & see if that works. If not, paste the results of `dput(head(df_high_A, 10))` so that we have a better idea of your data structure.

Comment: @ Z.lin yes, now it is working. Thank you so much Z.Lin. My respect

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is

```
dput( df_high_A )
structure(list(C1 = c(10L, 20L, 14L), C2 = c(23L, 12L, 17L)), .Names = c("C1", 
"C2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("02-01-07", "03-01-07", 
"04-01-07"))
```

With Base R, a solution would be

```
df_high_A <- data.frame( "C1" = row.names( df_high_A ), 
                         "C2" = df_high_A$C1, 
                         "C3" = df_high_A$C2 )
```

which yields

```
df_high_A
        C1 C2 C3
1 02-01-07 10 23
2 03-01-07 20 12
3 04-01-07 14 17
```

Comment: thank you for the solution but it is a big data frame. putting date individually is impossible.

Comment: Then more info about the real data may be helpful. I don't know `tibble()` but I'm sure Base R has a workable solution for the problem.

Comment: it is a stock market daily data for 10 years. so it is big.

Comment: OK but what do you want to do with it? Is the naming as per your example important, or is it just the XLS column number thing? Is the renaming of columns important at all? Could the vector with the rownames/dates sit at the end of the dataframe? Without knowing what you want to do it's difficult to give advice.

Comment: yes, it is the daily stock price data. so it is important for the analysis.

Comment: Ihave already developed many codes with the format I wanted. that is why it would be very helpfull.

Comment: How about something like `df_high_A <- cbind(rownames(df_high_A), df_high_A); colnames(df_high_A) <- paste0("C, 1:ncol(df_high_A)`?

Answer (score 0):

If your rownames are always going to be the dates you can try to bind them together, then reset the column and row names.

```
df_high_A = cbind(rownames(df_high_A), df_high_A)
colnames(df_high_A) = paste("C",1:ncol(df_high_A),sep="")
rownames(df_high_A) = 1:nrow(df_high_A)
```